# How to do an integration test to pick file?

Tags: flutter

I have a registration feature in which users have to select the profile image.

The app will open the photos or take them on the camera, and I don't know how to pick an image on the integration test.

I want to create an integration test to ensure the user can select an image and upload it to the server. Can I make an integration test on the pick image feature?

Comment: 1-Question  may be answered  base on  personal  Opinion /2-Question needs some code